# What's the Redux pattern for updating a single property

Tags: redux, react-redux

From all the reading i've done, all I can see for updating single properties in a reducer is to create an action for updating that property.  Is the accepted pattern really to make an action for every property?

For example, let's say I had a todo reducer with a default state with three different properties.  Is the expected pattern to create 3 different update actions, one for each property, like this?

```
const todo = ({
    text: '',
    complete: false,
    assignedUser: null
}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_TEXT':
            return {...state, text: action.payload}
        case 'UPDATE_COMPLETE':
            return {...state, complete: action.payload}
        case 'UPDATE_ASSIGNEDUSER':
            return {...state, assignedUser: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

If not a separate update action for each property, then what are people doing as the pattern for updating each property?

Comment: Usually each property unless they have some interrelation

Comment: Like in most things in development: "It depends" ... I have actions that change a single flag because that's all it calls for. I have other actions that invoke an api call and then create two arrays out of the data and store the data in two separate stores.  And I have actions that are varying degrees of difficulties in between. The point is that the reducer updates as much or as little as it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is another way and maybe can help you:

```js
const todo = ({
    text: '',
    complete: false,
    assignedUser: null
}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE':
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Now, everything you pass by action's payload, will enter into the state, for example:

```js
const updateTodo = payload => ({type: "UPDATE", payload})
dispatch(updateTodo({
    complete: true, 
    text: "Hello world", 
    assignedUser: {}
}))
```